# CSS3 Shadowbox - on bottom only

Tags: html, css, shadowbox

I am attempting to place a shadow at the bottom of the .top_section of my code. However, I cannot make it work. I have two sections (a top and a bottom), the shadow needs to go bellow the .top_section

Here is the code:

CSS:

```
.top_section {
    background-image: url(../images/background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#boxShadow{box-shadow: 10px 10pxrgba(0, 0, 0, .4);} 

.bottom_section {
background-image: url(../images/background.png);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid top_section">
<div id="boxShadow">
<section>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4 offset4">
        <br />
            <img src="images/logo.png" width="400" height="400" image alt="image" />
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row12">
        <h3><p class="text-center">ANIMATOR & DIGITAL ILLUSTRATOR</p></h3>
        <h4><p class="text-center">I'M MARK FROM SINGAPORE, I DESIGN & MAKE THINGS MOVE.   </p></h4>
        <h4><p class="text-center">I AM CURRENTLY FREELANCING AND STUDYING AT ANIMATION MENTOR.</p></h4>
        <br />
        <br />
 </div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span1 offset4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="images/MAIL_icon.png" width="50" height="50" image alt="image" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="span1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="images/DRIBBBLE_icon.png" width="50" height="50" image alt="image" />
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="span1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="images/TWITTER_icon.png" width="50" height="50" image alt="image" />
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="span1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="images/INSTAGRAM_icon.png" width="50" height="50" image alt="image" />
            </a>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</section>

</div>

</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply achieve it by setting the `#boxShadow` as:

```
#boxShadow {
    box-shadow: 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
```

---

You can take a reading of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/box-shadow) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is with your code is just a typo in the boxShadow, otherwise it seems to work fine on this fiddle: [typo fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wSSrz/)

Just needed a space between 10px and rgba.

```
#boxShadow { box-shadow: 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4); }
```

Is this what you are looking for?
Edited to remove right-side shadow.

Here's a full tutorial of box-shadow, including cross-platform (and older browser) browser-specific prefixes: [CSS3 Box Shadow Tutorial](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/)

Comment: Sorry, but your solution places the shadow on the sides and not on the bottom.

Comment: Oh, in that case the first value of box-shadow must simply be set to 0. Updated fiddle and editing answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify this : http://jsfiddle.net/KyuH7/

```
<div id="box_wrapper">
   <div id="box">
   </div>
   <div id="box_shadow">
   </div>
</div>

#box_wrapper{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}

#box_wrapper #box{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    background:#FFF;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:3;
}

#box_wrapper #box_shadow{
   width:290px;
   height:50px;
   background:#CCC;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:5px;
   z-index:0;
   box-shadow:0px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}
```